# Dynamic HTML page content

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Let's say I want to show different items each time the user changes the search options.
I get the new items by AJAX (This is mandatory so I can't use the POST, so I can't use the {% for %} loop of django template).
Currently, I take the returned list of items, and pass it to a javascript function that generates HTML code. This function is not more than concatenating strings together and forming the new HTML content.

A simple example:

```
function build_items_list(items_list, container){
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i=0; i<items_list.length; i+=1){
        var item = items_list[i];
        container.innerHTML += '<div>' +
                               '<input type="checkbox" id="' + item.id.toString() + '">' + 
                               '<a href="' + item.url+'"><b>' + item.name + '</b></a>'+
                               '</div>'

    }
}
```

Obviously, it is not the best way to generate the content, and I have many similar contents to generate.

What is the right way to generate such contents?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why python and django ?

Comment: It is the project. Django, Python and AJAX are not optional.

Comment: It is a scientific project and many many libraries are being used in the backend with python.

Comment: But this specific problem, I think there is no role of djnago and python

Comment: So nothing is equivalent to JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no right way.
The way youre doing it is fine.
That being said, I have had to create content many times in JavaScript and so came up with a function to generate content. It can be modified easily and I find it keeps code, imo, cleaner.

```
function createElement(element, attributes, text) {
    // function to create an element with class and text if wanted.
    // attributes is an object of key value items. Key is the attribute, value is the value.
    // you could change the "class" to an argument and use it to set anyAttribute
    var el = document.createElement(element);
    $.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
        el.setAttribute(key, value);
    });
    if (text) {
        var t = document.createTextNode(text);
        el.appendChild(t);
    }
    return el;
}
```

for an example the above can be called like so:

```
createElement("div", { 
    "class": "btn btn-default btn-sm btn-gene col-md-4", 
    "value": value }, "remove item")
```

This creates a the following element

```
<div class"btn btn-default btn-sm btn-gene col-md-4" value="value">remove item</div>
```

Youre still going to be building elements in JavaScript and appending them to the DOM, which is a bit of work, but I found it helps with DRY.

On the other side of that you can use, as @Or Duan said, a frontend framework or, you can use a frontend templating engine.
Frameworks usually contain templating engines and data bind values in so that they change when the values change, but you can do the logic yourself and just use the template engine outside of a framework.
Depending on your needs there are a variety of templating engines - https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: Thank you very much. your answer was really helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but there is no easy solution, this is why libraries like Angular, Ember etc are so successful, you can bind js variables into templates.

You could write many functions like you did for each template, but consider using 3th party library.

Example of your code in angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items_list">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}">
        <a href="{{item.url}}"><b>{{item.name}}</b></a>
    </div>
</div>
```